# SQL Server Hidden Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has three columns one of which is only used to get an increment number that is added to a string in another column. So I am trying to make it so that the column I don't want to see will never show up in an any matter. I know that I can just not select the column when doing a "Select" statement but I wanted to find out if there was another more permanent way to hide it.

Here is the output that I get:

```
INV   CUST_ID   FIRST_NAME
--------------------------
101   Cus101    Bob
102   Cus102    Jim
```

And here is how I want it to look:

```
CUST_ID FIRST_NAME
------------------
Cus101  Bob
Cus102  Jim
```

Here is the SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE tblcustomer 
(
    INV INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(101,1), 
    CUST_ID AS CONCAT('Cus', INV) PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
);
```

Also feel free to let me know if you see another way that I can achieve this without the "INV" column.

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow OP has an identity column. Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: Hidden from who / what? and what is the purpose? You are solving a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a view:

```
create v_customer as
    select cust_id, first_name
     from tblcustomer;
```

Then  use `v_customer` instead of `tblcustomer`.

I'm not 100% sure that I really encourage to do this.  I think you are better off getting used to `inv` as the primary key.  There is no need to convert it to an string.  For instance, you should be using `inv` and not `cust_id` for foreign key relationships.